# Reestructurar condiciones if

Tags: javascript, sonar

En SonarQUBE me genera este *issue*, el cual comenta que no puede tener más de 3 if/switch/while anidados, en este caso es el IF, y me pide reestructurarlo pero no se exactamente cómo. Dejo el código.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {
    if (i < data.length) {
         item = data[i];
         name = $.trim(item.nombre);
         //Marca ISSUE en este if
         if (staStr === name) {
              valSel += "," + "'" + item.id + "'";
         } else {
              $('#estatus_folio').append($('<option>', {
               value: valSel,
               text: staStr
               }));
              valSel = "'" + item.id + "'";
              staStr = name;
         }
    } else {
         staStr = $.trim(data[data.length - 2].nombre);
         item = data[data.length - 1];
         name = $.trim(item.nombre);
         //Marca ISSUE en este if
         if (staStr !== name) {
              valSel = "'" + item.id + "'";
         }
         $('#estatus_folio').append($('<option>', {
          value: valSel,
           text: name
           }));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Analicemos un segundo tu codigo...

```
for (var i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {
    if (i < data.length) {...
```

Y ya con eso alcanza.. i siempre es menor a data.length, salvo en la ultima vuelta...

Entonces toda la segunda parte de ese if, no tiene ningun sentido, salvo para la ultima vuelta.. o sea, que se puede sacar afuera.. y entonces sacamos ese if que no aporta absolutamente nada.

Para ello, cambiemos el for a

```
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { //Quite el igual
```

Dentro del for queda solamente lo que tenia el if original (cuando entrabamos por true):

```
item = data[i];
name = $.trim(item.nombre);
//Marca ISSUE en este if
if (staStr === name) {
    valSel += "," + "'" + item.id + "'";
} else {
    $('#estatus_folio').append($('<option>', {
    value: valSel,
    text: staStr
    }));
    valSel = "'" + item.id + "'";
    staStr = name;
}
```

Y al salir del for, ejecutamos lo que teniamos en el else, ya que no fuimos hasta data.length, si no hasta el elemento anterior:

```
staStr = $.trim(data[data.length - 2].nombre);
item = data[data.length - 1];
name = $.trim(item.nombre);
//Marca ISSUE en este if
if (staStr !== name) {
    valSel = "'" + item.id + "'";
}
$('#estatus_folio').append($('<option>', {
value: valSel,
text: name
}));
```